# run local HTTP or SOCK proxy through openvpn

Tags: networking, proxy, openvpn, http-proxy

I have a little problem with my OpenVPN client-side configuration. I wanna connect to my OpenVPN server " I using ovpnconnector in command line " :

```
> ovpnconnector install
> ovpnconnector set-config profile D:\profile.ovpn
> ovpnconnector start
```

ipconfig :

```
Unknown adapter Local Area Connection: 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4dab:ab8e:48d1:858%25
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.2
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.1
```

and I can be connected successfully and dev tun has been created but I want to use a local " HTTP or Socks Local proxy " to connect with it to the dev tun on my OpenVPN connection and forward all traffic of specific apps that supports HTTP or socks proxies but I don't know how to do it. I search for solutions and I found something but all of them using TCP but I run a UDP profile and I couldn't change it to TCP

I scan 10.8.0.2 for open ports with angryIP Scanner but I didn't found any open Port

Comment: OpenVPN can **use** a HTTP proxy to connect to the other endpoint, but does not **provide** a HTTP proxy. You'll have to install one on the server side.

Comment: so there is no way to create an HTTP proxy and connected to tun of openvpn in my local ?

Comment: What packet is sent through `tun` and which one directly through a physical interface is based on the [routing table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table) (`route print` on Windows). Can you [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1051741/edit) your question and state what you want to achieve ultimately (_I want to route traffic through OpenVPN based on..._) and also add the `windows` tag, so people can provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Piotr P. Karwasz has mentioned, OpenVPN at least itself does not provide the HTTPS/SOCKS5 function. Besides, I have used such function via ssh client service, it does not always work out. There are still many websites imcompatible to such proxies.

What you really want is the normal visit on WWW stays the same, but use OpenVPN to visit some specific sites or IPs. I suggest Not using the VPN gateway as the default router, as you just set in OpenVPN configurations. Instead, specify where you wanna visit through the OpenVPN. For example destination_IP=8.8.8.8:
`route 8.8.8.8 255.255.255.255`

Make sure there is no other routing policies in your client configuration or in your server configuration with "push" at the beginning. No "def1" either. Then with this line only in the client configuration, you visit 8.8.8.8 via VPN channel while all the other places using the old router at your home.